# While dentro de função mail

Tags: php, envio-de-email, while

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:
Quero fazer com que os resultados de um While (Basicamente 10 registros), sejam inseridos dentro da função mail.
Não faço a menor ídeia de como farei isso, alguém poderá me ajudar.

Quero que cada resultado seja exibido exatamente onde está "Aqui vem o resultado 1 do While" e etc...

Abaixo o código mais exemplificado para os amigos do stack poderem me ajudar:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_microf, $microf);
$query_sa1 = "SELECT * FROM sa1 WHERE  mesvenc='$mes' AND situacao='Pendente'  ";
$sa1 = mysql_query($query_sa1, $microf) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sa1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sa1);
$totalRows_sa1 = mysql_num_rows($sa1);


mysql_select_db($database_microf, $microf);
$query_sa12 = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM sa1 WHERE  mesvenc='$mes' AND situacao='Pendente'  ";
$sa12 = mysql_query($query_sa12, $microf) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sa12 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sa12);
$totalRows_sa12 = mysql_num_rows($sa12);

$total=$totalRows_sa1;
$valor=number_format($row_sa12['SUM(valor)'],2,',','.');


if($totalRows_sa1>0){

//hader para o e-mail ir com codificações corretas e tudo mais.
$headers .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
//
$destino = 'meuemail@meudominio.com';
$nome="Sistema Financeiro";
$email="no-reply@meudominio.com";

//Envia mensagem para o administrador do site
$resposta = mail("$destino","Relatorio de Contas Pendentes",
"<p><b>Atenção!</b></p>

-------------------------------------------------</br>

Existem <b>$total</b> contas  do mês de <b>$mes</b> que ainda não foram pagas.</br>
Elas Totalizam <b>R$ $valor</b> </br>

As contas a serem pagas são:
Aqui vem o resultado 1 do While</br>
Aqui vem o resultado 2 do while</br>
Aqui vem o resultado 3 do while</br>




Verifique por favor...</br>
<a href='http://meudominio.com'><img src='http://meudominio.com/cron/images/BtnAcessarSistema.png' /></a></br>

--------------------------------------------------</br>
<p>Essa é uma mensagem enviada através do seu sistema. Não Responda.</p>
","$headers"."From:$nome<$email>");




?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras para voce fazer isso, uma delas seria atribuir uma variável qualquer para o texto tipo e rescrever nessa variável o texto dentro do loop com o que vc quiser, eu faria algo tipo :

```
<?php
$relatorio = '';
$query = pdo->query($meuSql);
foreach(row as query)
{
    $relatorio .= "coluna1 : ".row['colunatabela']."/n".
                  "coluna2 : ".row['colunatabela2'];
    // ...
}

$headers .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$mensagem = "Relatorio mensal das suas contas pendentes. \n\n\n".
            "--------------------------------------------------\n".
            $relatorio.
            "--------------------------------------------------\n".
            "seu rodapé do email.bla bla bla\n";
$destino = 'meuemail@meudominio.com';
$nome="Sistema Financeiro";
$email="no-reply@meudominio.com";
$subject = $nome." - Relaório mensal de contas...bla.bla.bla\n";
mail($destino, $subject, $mensagem, $headers);
?>
```

Lenbrando que para adicionar texto em variáveis no php, vc tem de usar "texto".$variavel_text."mais texto".$outravar."mais outro text"."etc.";
e se voce quiser um loop dentro do outro voce faz um outro "foreach(...)" ou while (...) dentro do primeiro loop, no meu caso a linha: **foreach(row as query)**, dai, fica a seu critério.

Isso é só o começo, no mais, põe os neuronios pra queimar, a "poupança" para encaliçar e derriça o dedo no código, ririri

saúde e paz!

Comment: Obrigado Armando, me ajudou bastante era isso mesmo que precisava.
Um forte abraço.